# How to get RdotNet into Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio, r.net

I have downloaded the rdotnet package from github, now I'm not sure what i need to do to get it into the directory of Visual Studio so that I can start using R in C#. I'm a novice coder, and this is way beyond my scope of knowledge. I've also downloaded the package in R. I also am using Visual Studio Express 2017

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use [nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget) to manage dependencies like this. There is a fairly good [getting started guide](http://rdotnet.github.io/rdotnet/getting_started/) for R.Net that goes thru the installation process step by step.

Comment: What an easy to follow guide! I could not find anything this simple for the life of me. Thank you!! You're a life saver.